# Regex to find a specific pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
{
    "rows": 10,
    "os": "0",
    "page": "1",
    "total": "1",
    "peoples": {
        "123": {
            "url": "http://google.com",
            "id": "123",
            "fname": "Rob",
            "lname": "Tom",
            "full_name_ac": "Rob Tom"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a regex to get a full name in c# something like **/("full_name_ac": ")\w**+, but not able to write.Please help me to write the regex that will always find the value under double quotes for full_name_ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegEx to extract a `full_name_ac`value out of this string should look like

```
(?<="full_name_ac": ")[\w\ ]+(?=\")
```

**Explaination:**

`(?<="full_name_ac": ")`  - starts with `"full_name_ac": "` but it's not a part of the value

`[\w\ ]+` the name including space with at lease one character

`(?=\")` and the string has to end with a `"` which isn't a part of the value